# Calculating mean total seasonal precipitation using python

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I am new to python and using it to analyse climate data in NetCDF. I am wanting to calculate the total precipitation for each season in each year and then average these seasonal totals across the time period (i.e. an average for DJF over all years in the file and an average for MAM etc.).
Here is what I thought to do:

```
fn1 = 'cru_fixed.nc'
ds1 = xr.open_dataset(fn1)
ds1_season = ds1['pre'].groupby('time.season').mean('time')
#Then plot each season
ds1_season.plot(col='season')
plt.show()
```

The original file contains monthly totals of precipitation. This is calculating an average for each season and I need the sum of Dec, Jan and Feb  and the sum of Mar, Apr, May etc. for each season in each year. How do I sum and then average over the years?

Comment: Have you done anything to check your doubt? You're the one with the data

Comment: Yes I also did it using CDO and the totals are higher in CDO that with this method and that is why I don't think it is calculating the total (sum) for each season first.

Comment: I'm not quite sure to understand your issue, when you do `ds1['pre'].groupby('time.season')`, you will create 4 groups 'DJF', 'JJA', 'MAM', 'SON'. And within each group you have the values on multiple years. To make sure of this, you can try something like `gr = ds1['pre'].groupby('time.season')` and then `gr['DJF']`

Comment: @Abel Thanks for your comment. Yes I understand it creates the groups of each season on multiple years, but, as I understand, the values within each season are averaged for the season of each year, and I need the sum for each year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaking, you need to first resample you data to have the sum of each seasons on a DataArray, then to average theses sum on multiple years.

To resample:

`sum_of_seasons = ds1['pre'].resample(time='Q').sum(dim="time")`
[resample](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.resample.html?highlight=resample) is an operator to upsample or downsample time series, it uses [time offsets of pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects).
However be careful to choose the right offset, it will define the month included in each season. Depending on your needs, you may want to use "Q", "QS" or an anchored offset like "QS-DEC".
To have the same splitting as "time.season", the offset is "QS-DEC" I believe.

Then to group over multiple years, same as you did above:
`result = sum_of_seasons.groupby('time.season').mean('time')`

Comment: thanks this was exactly what I was looking for.